# DataBind Listbox SubSelection in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, listbox

Okay, I might be asking an age old question, but I did not get my scenario described in any of them.

I have an Oject which can contain several child Objects. Eg. A Project obejct can have several Resource objects. I have an ObservaleCollection with super set of child obejcts (in my case Resource objects). I also have another ObservableCollection in Project object containing existing childs.

What is the best way to present this to user in WPF windows application? I also need to provide a way for them to chnage the mapping as well.

My initial idea was to use classic Double List approach, with two listboxes, but I am not sure how easy it would be to manipulate view layer alone.

```
[Resoure Collection]             [Resoure Collection in a Project]  
--------------------             ---------------------------------  
|Resource 1        |      >      |Resource 3                     |  
|Resource 2        |      >>     |Resource 4                     |  
|Resource 5        |      <      |                               |  
|Resource 6        |      <<     |                               |  
|Resource 7        |             |                               |
```

I need similar UI for 4 more similar mappings of different objects. I tried to move this to a user control, but looks like I can't have Generic collection (private ObservableCollection) in an UserControl.

Any ideas from experience members?

/**************************************************************************************/
Edit: THis is what I got so far, note that I am going with UserControl since I need the same UI in multiple screens, and I feel UserCOntrol will give me more manageable code.

XAML for the user control

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="TimeTracker.ItemsSelectionLists"
             x:Name="ItemsSelectionControl">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid Background="#FFF9FDFD"
              Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock x:Name="SourceHeading"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Margin="8,8,0,0"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Text="Whole Team"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <ListBox x:Name="SourceItemsList"
                     Grid.Column="0"
                     Margin="8,30,8,8"
                     MinWidth="150"
                     SelectionMode="Multiple"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Collection1}"/>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="0"
                        Orientation="Vertical"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Button Content="&gt;"
                        Height="25"
                        Width="25" />
                <Button Content="&gt;&gt;"
                        Height="25"
                        Width="25" />
                <Button Content="&lt;"
                        Height="25"
                        Width="25" />
                <Button Content="&lt;&lt;"
                        Height="25"
                        Width="25" />
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock x:Name="TargetHeading"
                       Grid.Column="2"
                       Margin="8,8,8,0"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Text="Current Team"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <ListBox x:Name="SelectedItemsList"
                     Grid.Column="2"
                     Margin="8,30,8,8"
                     MinWidth="150"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Collection2}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ItemsSelectionLists.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ItemsSelectionLists: UserControl
    {
        [Bindable(true)]

        internal ObservableCollection<TrackerItem> SourceList
        {
            get
            {
                return _vm.Collection1;
            }
            set
            {
                _vm.Collection1 = value;
            }
        }

        private readonly ViewModel _vm; 

        public ItemsSelectionLists()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            _vm = new ViewModel();
            this.DataContext = _vm; 
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Properties

        private ObservableCollection<TrackerItem> _collection1;

        /// <summary> 
        /// This is the first collection. 
        /// </summary> 
        internal ObservableCollection<TrackerItem> Collection1
        {
            get
            {
                return _collection1;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != _collection1)
                {
                    _collection1 = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Collection1");
                }
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<TrackerItem> _collection2;

        /// <summary> 
        /// This is the second collection. 
        /// </summary> 
        internal ObservableCollection<TrackerItem> Collection2
        {
            get
            {
                return _collection2;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != _collection2)
                {
                    _collection2 = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Collection2");
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        /// <summary> 
        /// Default constructor. 
        /// </summary> 
        public ViewModel()
        {
            // Create initial collections. 

            // Populate first collection with sample data 
            _collection1 = new ObservableCollection<TrackerItem>();
            // Seconf collection is empty 
            _collection2 = new ObservableCollection<TrackerItem>();
        }

        #endregion

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Main Window

```
<TabItem Header="Resource Allocation">
    <local:ItemsSelectionLists x:Name="ResourceSelection"/>
</TabItem>
```

Code

```
ResourceSelection.SourceList = MainObject.Resources;
//error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<TimeTracker.Resource>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<TimeTracker.TrackerItem>'
```

Comment: I am working up a sample. I will have it shortly.

Comment: Thank you, looking forward to it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not graceful or polished, but here is a workable sample. If I made this polished I would have implemented true MVVM, but as a sample, this will get you started.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TwoListboxes.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListBox x:Name="List1" Grid.Column="0" 
                 Height="200" Margin="10" 
                 SelectionMode="Multiple"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Collection1}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Content="&gt;" Width="60" Click="MoveRightEvent" />
            <Button Content="&gt;&gt;" Width="60" Click="MoveAllRightEvent" />
            <Button Content="&lt;&lt;" Width="60" Click="MoveAllLeftEvent" />
            <Button Content="&lt;" Width="60" Click="MoveLeftEvent" />
        </StackPanel>

        <ListBox x:Name="List2" Grid.Column="2" 
                 Height="200" Margin="10" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Collection2}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code-behind:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    #region Members

    private readonly ViewModel<TrackerItem> _vm;

    #endregion

    public MainWindow()
    {
        // Get viewmodel and set context
        _vm = new ViewModel<TrackerItem>();
        _vm.Collection1 = new ObservableCollection<TrackerItem>
            {
                new TrackerItem { Name = "Item1", Value = "1"},
                new TrackerItem { Name = "Item2", Value = "2"},
                new TrackerItem { Name = "Item3", Value = "3"},
                new TrackerItem { Name = "Item4", Value = "4"},
                new TrackerItem { Name = "Item5", Value = "5"},
                new TrackerItem { Name = "Item6", Value = "6"},
                new TrackerItem { Name = "Item7", Value = "7"},
                new TrackerItem { Name = "Item8", Value = "8"},
                new TrackerItem { Name = "Item9", Value = "9"},
                new TrackerItem { Name = "Item10", Value = "10"}
            };
        this.DataContext = _vm;

        // Initialize UI
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Moves selected items in a list from one collection to another.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="list"></param>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <param name="destination"></param>
    private void MoveItems(ListBox list,
        ObservableCollection<TrackerItem> source,
        ObservableCollection<TrackerItem> destination)
    {
        if (list.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            // List for items to be removed.
            var hitList = new List<TrackerItem>();

            // Move items
            foreach (var selectedItem in list.SelectedItems)
            {
                var item = selectedItem as TrackerItem;
                if (item != null)
                {
                    // Tag item for removal
                    hitList.Add(item);

                    // Check if item is in target list
                    var targetList = (from p in destination
                                      where p == item
                                      select p).ToList();

                    // Add to destination
                    if (!targetList.Any())
                    {
                        destination.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Remove items
            foreach (var hitItem in hitList)
            {
                // Remove item
                source.Remove(hitItem);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Moves all items from one list to another.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <param name="destination"></param>
    private void MoveAllItems(
        ObservableCollection<TrackerItem> source,
        ObservableCollection<TrackerItem> destination)
    {
        // List for items to be removed.
        var hitList = new List<TrackerItem>();

        // Move items
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                // Tag item for removal
                hitList.Add(item);

                // Check if item is in target list
                var targetList = (from p in destination
                                  where p == item
                                  select p).ToList();

                // Add to destination
                if (!targetList.Any())
                {
                    destination.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        // Remove items
        foreach (var hitItem in hitList)
        {
            // Remove item
            source.Remove(hitItem);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Click event: moves selected items to the right.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void MoveRightEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MoveItems(List1, _vm.Collection1, _vm.Collection2);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Click event: moves all items to the right..
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void MoveAllRightEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MoveAllItems(_vm.Collection1, _vm.Collection2);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Click event: moves all items to the left.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void MoveAllLeftEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MoveAllItems(_vm.Collection2, _vm.Collection1);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Click event: moves selected items to the left.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void MoveLeftEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MoveItems(List2, _vm.Collection2, _vm.Collection1);
    }
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Properties

    private ObservableCollection<T> _collection1;

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the first collection.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<T> Collection1
    {
        get { return _collection1; }

        set
        {
            if (value != _collection1)
            {
                _collection1 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Collection1");
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<T> _collection2;

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the second collection.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<T> Collection2
    {
        get { return _collection2; }

        set
        {
            if (value != _collection2)
            {
                _collection2 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Collection2");
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public ViewModel()
    {
        // Create initial collections.

        // Populate first collection with sample data
        _collection1 = new ObservableCollection<T>();

        // Seconf collection is empty
        _collection2 = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    }

    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

TrackerItem

```
public class TrackerItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;

    /// <summary>
    /// A name.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }

        set
        {
            if (value != _name)
            {
                _name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _value;

    /// <summary>
    /// A value.
    /// </summary>
    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }

        set
        {
            if (value != _value)
            {
                _value = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort Xcalibur!! I already tried something similar before asking the question except for the view Model. The problem I have is in each of the screens I need to use this control the type of the object will be different. So the need to have it in a user control and have ObservableCollection<T> insead of ObservableCollection<string>. I will try this solution, and revert back.

Comment: In that case why not use an abstract class class under all your custom objects instead of T? Then you can use Liskov substitution.

Comment: I have an abstract class called TrackerItem which is then derived by all my other classes. Now I tried ObservableCollection<TrackerItem> SourceList, and in the main window I tried xxx.SourceList = xxxx.Resources;
This gives error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<TimeTracker.Resource>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<TimeTracker.TrackerItem>
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for spending time for me. I have edited my original post with the updated code. I shamelessly took your ViewModel class.

Comment: I think one issue is the local observable collection you are creating in the UserControl. You can manipulate everything with the 2 collections in the viewmodel. I don't know where you are setting the direct assignment, but that would not work without a Cast and that is not what you want because you will reset the object context. Handle the base class in the 2 methods I put in the code behind. Then it's straight manipulation, not rebinding of sources.

Comment: Okay, I went back with your generics approach and added my own TrackerItem. The viewmodel handles the generic. You can invoke a usercontrol with a generic with XAML2009. However, I find the best way (though a hack of sorts) is to create the base class, write a simple wrapper for your specific datatype that inherits from the base class with that instance, and then use that wrapper as the object source for your user control.

Comment: so in every screen I create a View Model which will have specific versions of the abstract class collections? and the UserControl will be just two listboxes and the button code?

Comment: If you are looking to pass a generic to XAML you can't do that.

Comment: Essentially you would have to reproduce the XAML each time, but all the underlying intelligence in the code-behind and the ViewModel can be abstract.

Comment: I did complete a usercontrol, which can show generic lists, provided they are in a viewmodel. I have posted the code as an answer. I am marking your answer as "Answer" since it actually guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad I could help. And the way you did it is exactly how developers get around that issue now.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks to Reflection and XCalibur's viewmodel idea, I am able to complete my user control, which can show contents of two generic observable collections of same type. The consumer of the control can specify the property of the objects listboxes should show. The collection data would be copied to local collection, and hence any changes made to the collections won't change the input collections.

**XAML:**

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TimeTracker"
         x:Class="TimeTracker.ItemsSelectionLists"
         x:Name="ItemsSelectionControl">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:DummyConverter x:Key="DummyConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid Background="#FFF9FDFD"
          Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                   Margin="8,8,0,0"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Text="{Binding Path=LeftHeader, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <ListBox x:Name="LeftItemsList"
                 Grid.Column="0"
                 Margin="8,30,8,8"
                 MinWidth="150"
                 SelectionMode="Multiple"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LeftCollection}" />
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                    Margin="0"
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Content="&gt;"
                    Height="25"
                    Width="25"
                    Click="Button_Click" />
            <Button Content="&gt;&gt;"
                    Height="25"
                    Width="25"
                    Click="Button_Click" />
            <Button Content="&lt;"
                    Height="25"
                    Width="25"
                    Click="Button_Click" />
            <Button Content="&lt;&lt;"
                    Height="25"
                    Width="25"
                    Click="Button_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"
                   Margin="8,8,8,0"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Text="{Binding Path=RightHeader, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <ListBox x:Name="RightItemsList"
                 Grid.Column="2"
                 Margin="8,30,8,8"
                 MinWidth="150"
                 SelectionMode="Multiple"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RightCollection}" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**User control code**

```
public partial class ItemsSelectionLists : UserControl
 {
    #region properties
    public string LeftHeader
    {
        get
        {
            return (string) GetValue(LeftHeaderProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(LeftHeaderProperty, value);
        }
    }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for LeftHeader.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LeftHeaderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LeftHeader", typeof(string), typeof(ItemsSelectionLists), new UIPropertyMetadata("Left List Header"));

    public string RightHeader
    {
        get
        {
            return (string) GetValue(RightHeaderProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(RightHeaderProperty, value);
        }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for RightHeader.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RightHeaderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("RightHeader", typeof(string), typeof(ItemsSelectionLists), new UIPropertyMetadata("Right List Header"));

    private object dataSource;
    public object DataSource
    {
        get
        {
            return dataSource;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!value.GetType().FullName.StartsWith("TimeTracker.ViewModel"))
                throw new ArgumentException("DataSource is not an instance of ViewModel");
            if (dataSource != value)
            {
                dataSource = value;
                this.DataContext = this.DataSource;
                DataTemplateSelector templateSelector = dataSource as DataTemplateSelector;
                this.LeftItemsList.ItemTemplateSelector = templateSelector;
                this.RightItemsList.ItemTemplateSelector = templateSelector;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public ItemsSelectionLists()
        : base()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        var type = dataSource.GetType();
        var MoveItems = type.GetMethod("MoveItems");
        var MoveAllItems = type.GetMethod("MoveAllItems");
        switch (button.Content.ToString())
        {
            case ">":
            MoveItems.Invoke(dataSource, new object[] { LeftItemsList, true });
            break;
            case ">>":
            MoveAllItems.Invoke(dataSource, new object[] { true });
            break;
            case "<":
            MoveItems.Invoke(dataSource, new object[] { RightItemsList, false });
            break;
            case "<<":
            MoveAllItems.Invoke(dataSource, new object[] { false });
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel<T> : DataTemplateSelector, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Properties

    //this is just a placeholder for the collection, no changes will be made to this collection
    private ObservableCollection<T> leftCollectionRef;
    //local collection
    private ObservableCollection<T> leftCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<T> LeftCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return leftCollection;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != leftCollectionRef)
            {
                //remove subscription to previous collection
                if (leftCollectionRef != null)
                    leftCollectionRef.CollectionChanged -= new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Ref_CollectionChanged);
                leftCollectionRef = value;
                leftCollection.Clear();
                foreach (var item in leftCollectionRef)
                {
                    if (rightCollection.IndexOf(item) == -1)
                        leftCollection.Add(item);
                }

                NotifyPropertyChanged("LeftCollection");
                //subscribe to chnages in new collection
                leftCollectionRef.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Ref_CollectionChanged);
            }
        }
    }


    //this is just a placeholder for the collection, no changes will be made to this collection
    private ObservableCollection<T> rightCollectionRef;
    private ObservableCollection<T> rightCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<T> RightCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return rightCollection;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != rightCollectionRef)
            {
                //remove subscription to previous collection
                if (rightCollectionRef != null)
                    rightCollectionRef.CollectionChanged -= new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Ref_CollectionChanged);
                rightCollectionRef = value;
                rightCollection.Clear();
                foreach (var item in rightCollectionRef)
                {
                    if (leftCollection.IndexOf(item) == -1)
                        rightCollection.Add(item);
                }

                NotifyPropertyChanged("RightCollection");
                rightCollectionRef.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Ref_CollectionChanged);
            }
        }
    }

    private string bindingMember;
    public string BindingMember
    {
        get
        {
            return bindingMember;
        }
        set
        {
            var mem = typeof(T).GetProperty(value);
            if (mem == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("No Member " + value + " found in " + this.GetType().FullName);
            if (bindingMember != value)
            {
                bindingMember = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("BindingMember");
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
    #region Constructors

    public ViewModel()
        : base()
    {
        // internal collection, this will get items copied over from reference source collection
        leftCollection = new ObservableCollection<T>();
        // internal collection, this will get items copied over from reference target collection
        rightCollection = new ObservableCollection<T>();
        bindingMember = "";
    }

    #endregion
    #region Movements
    public void MoveItems(ListBox list, bool LeftToRight)
    {
        var source = leftCollection;
        var target = rightCollection;
        if (!LeftToRight)
        {
            target = leftCollection;
            source = rightCollection;
        }

        if (list.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            // List for items to be removed.
            var hitList = new List<T>();

            // Move items
            foreach (T item in list.SelectedItems)
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    // Tag item for removal
                    hitList.Add(item);
                    // Check if item is in target list
                    if (target.IndexOf(item) == -1)
                    {
                        target.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Remove items
            foreach (var hitItem in hitList)
            {
                source.Remove(hitItem);
            }
        }

    }
    public void MoveAllItems(bool LeftToRight)
    {
        if (LeftToRight)
        {
            rightCollection.Clear();
            foreach (var item in leftCollection)
            {
                RightCollection.Add(item);
            }
            leftCollection.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            leftCollection.Clear();
            foreach (var item in rightCollection)
            {
                leftCollection.Add(item);
            }
            rightCollection.Clear();
        }
    }

    #endregion
    #region collection-monitor
    private void Ref_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null && e.NewItems.Count > 0)
        {
            var target = leftCollection;
            if (sender == leftCollectionRef)
                target = leftCollection;
            else
                target = rightCollection;

            foreach (T item in e.NewItems)
            {
                target.Add(item);
            }
        }

        //try remove from both collections, since the item may have moved to right or left collections
        if (e.OldItems != null && e.OldItems.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (T item in e.OldItems)
            {
                leftCollection.Remove(item);
            }

            foreach (T item in e.OldItems)
            {
                rightCollection.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    #endregion
    #region templateselector
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {

        string dataTemplate =
            @"<DataTemplate  
            xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"">  
                <TextBlock Margin=""2"" TextWrapping=""Wrap"" Text=""{Binding Path=" + this.bindingMember + @", Mode=OneWay}""/>  
            </DataTemplate>";
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(dataTemplate);
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
        return XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as DataTemplate;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Using the control:

```
<TabItem Header="Resource Allocation">
<local:ItemsSelectionLists x:Name="ProjectResourceMap" LeftHeader="Whole Team" RightHeader="Current Project Team"/>
</TabItem>
<TabItem Header="Tasks for the Project">
<local:ItemsSelectionLists x:Name="ProjectTaskMap" Margin="0" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" LeftHeader="All Tasks" RightHeader="Current Project Tasks"/>
</TabItem>

ViewModel<Resource> ProjectResource = new ViewModel<Resource>();
ProjectResource.BindingMember = "ResourceName";
this.ProjectResourceMap.DataSource = ProjectResource;
ProjectResource.LeftCollection = timeTracker.Resources;

ViewModel<Task> ProjectTasks = new ViewModel<Task>();
ProjectTasks.BindingMember = "TaskName";
this.ProjectTaskMap.DataSource = ProjectTasks;
ProjectTasks.LeftCollection = timeTracker.Tasks;
```